How to reorder the columns in a barchart in ggplot2
I have the following data:
data <- data.frame(
 Category = c("A", "B", "C", "D"),
 Count = c(23, 17, 35, 29)
 )

Which I use to create the following bar-chart.
ggplot(data, aes(x = Category, y = Count, fill = Category)) +
 geom_bar(stat = "identity", color = "black") +
 labs(title = "Bar Chart Example", x = "Category", y = "Count") +
 theme_minimal()

This all works. However I would like to recorder the bars. So the view i want to create is C, A, D, B. Can anybdoy tell me how I can do this?

Try aes(x = factor(Category, c("C", "A", "D", "B")), ...)

...or scale_x_discrete(limits = c("C", "A", "D", "B")).
